# DocuSign - Creating a Payment Item via Rest API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create a Payment Item via the DocuSign API and I understand that to do so, I need to include a NumberTab and a FormulaTab. Our CRM, uses the AutoPlace functionality to place tabs on the document using the AnchorString property. A preview is shown so the user can check it before they send out the document and this all works fine.

However, when I create a new envelope, the tabs show up as a FormulaTab, not a payment item in the UI and then when I send the document, I can just complete the document without paying. The JSON I am sending across is as follows:

```
{"numberTabs":[{
    "tabLabel":"Number Test",
    "anchorString":"\\/Number 1\\/",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"false",
    "value":"1900.0",
    "editable":"false",
    "locked":"false",
    "isPaymentAmount":"true"
}],
"formulaTabs":[{
    "tabLabel":"Formula Test",
    "formula":"([Number Test])",
    "locked":"true",
    "required":"true",
    "hidden":"true",
    "anchorString":"\\/PayNow\\/",
    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":"false",
    "isPaymentAmount":"true",
    "paymentDetails":{
        "gatewayAccountId":"165be8b5-e212-43d4-b264-802d843f4182",
        "currencyCode":"GBP",
        "lineItems":[{
            "amountReference":"1900.0",
            "name":"AP-PACK-32 (2 days)",
            "description":"32 Advisory Points",
            "itemCode":346
        }]
    }
}]}
```

As I said when the document loads in DocuSign, the tab shows as a Formula tab, rather than displaying as a Payment Item so there must be something wrong with the above but I'm struggling to figure out what?

The last comment on this page: [DocuSign Payments REST API create Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164891/docusign-payments-rest-api-create-tab) gives an example, which is where I got the above from, but this doesn't work for me... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EXTRA INFO**

Since posting, I have now converted all amounts from strings to integers, just in case. I also tried setting the "isPaymentAmount" flag to true & false, and also leaving it out completely to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

1. Ignore isPaymentAmount flag , it is obsolete , you can remove
   it for both number and formula tab.
2. Formula property of Formula tab is the total amount that
   needs to be charged in cents - update it to ([Number Test]) * 100
3. Only payment line items (Number tabs here are visible in the document) remove anchor properties for formula.
4. amount reference property in payment details is a reference tab label to the line item, update it to "Number Test" . This indicates that the number item is payment line item.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm still not having any luck. I've removed "isPaymentAmount", and also the "anchor" properties. The payment line items bit doesn't necessarily make sense to me, I'm adding multiple Line Items to the "lines" array to represent one for each line on the document, the total of which is calculated by the CRM so the value that is added to the "Number Test" field is the total value. The "lines" array and amountReference is currently the individual line total. Even if I hard code the line array to one line item referencing the NumberTest as you suggest, it still doesn't work

Comment: I also don't need/want to multiply the amount by 100, I'm setting the currency to GBP and providing a total value. Multipling by 100, gives an incorrect amount as expected. For example £2850, would be £285,000!